# iOS app crashes randomly saying that failed to allocate memory for string

Tags: ios, memory, crash-reports

iOS app crashes randomly saying that **failed to allocate memory for string**. It **does not even generate low memory crash report**. According to apple documentation application termination due to low memory **generates a different type of low memory report**. But we are getting **normal crash report** looking like this.

```
Date/Time:           2017-04-11 14:23:47.2473 +0530
Launch Time:         2017-04-11 13:40:59.2931 +0530
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.3.2 (14F5065b)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000182651b84
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
BUG IN CLIENT OF LIBPLATFORM: Failed to allocate memory for string
Abort Cause 3

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x0000000182651b84 0x18264f000 + 11140
1   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x0000000182651b1c 0x18264f000 + 11036
2   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00000001825d16b4 0x1825c4000 + 54964
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00000001825ca75c 0x1825c4000 + 26460
4   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00000001825ca384 0x1825c4000 + 25476
5   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00000001825c57e8 0x1825c4000 + 6120
6   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x00000001825c8b80 0x1825c4000 + 19328
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000182017284 0x181ff0000 + 160388
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000182014e48 0x181ff0000 + 151112
9   CoreUI                          0x00000001894e4a50 0x18948e000 + 354896
10  CoreUI                          0x00000001894d600c 0x18948e000 + 294924
11  CoreUI                          0x00000001894f0ccc 0x18948e000 + 404684
12  CoreUI                          0x00000001894d5fa4 0x18948e000 + 294820
13  CoreUI                          0x00000001895013bc 0x18948e000 + 471996
14  UIKit                           0x000000018a01693c 0x1896b9000 + 9820476
15  UIKit                           0x000000018a016784 0x1896b9000 + 9820036
16  UIKit                           0x000000018a15b8d0 0x1896b9000 + 11151568
17  UIKit                           0x000000018a016fac 0x1896b9000 + 9822124
18  UIKit                           0x000000018998ad50 0x1896b9000 + 2956624
19  UIKit                           0x00000001897fd03c 0x1896b9000 + 1327164
```

Mostly the crash is happening while allocating the memory. Does the heap buffer overflow cause this? Can anyone please help in this? Thanks in advance.